# HealthKit background fetch without observing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, healthkit

I want to make regular HealthKit requests in the background in a BGTask. I don't want to observe changes in HealthKit necessarily. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query for HealthKit data in the background if your app is getting CPU run time. You just can't request authorization for data types since that prompts UI. If your app is authorized, then it should be able to read.